# .htaccess to redirect subdirectory to its own domain name

Tags: domains, htaccess, 301-redirect, folder

I have for example 2 domain names 
`gl.example` that points to `/public_html/` (which has subfolder `/public_html/tlf/`)
and `tlf.example` that points to the subfolder `/public_html/tlf/`

How do I redirect so that 
if users visit `https://gl.example/tlf/example.php` it goes to
`https://tlf.example/example.php`

Basically I want it everything under `gl.example/tlf` to look like it's on nte `tlf.example` domain.

Which *.htaccess* should I edit?  The one under `public_html/` or the one under `/public_html/tlf/`? Would it like do an infinite loop since `https://tlf.example` points to the same `/tlf` folder?

Comment: Why do you want to solve this in .htaccess?  It would normally be much better to create `public_html/gl/` and `public_html/tlf/` and set the document roots to those respective directories. It is never advisable to have domains in subdirectories of other domains.  For an example of the problems it causes see [Stop .htaccess automatically influencing subfolders](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48352/stop-htaccess-automatically-influencing-subfolders)

Comment: To add to Stephen Ostermiller answer I also strongly advise to not use .htaccess when possible and put the configuration in the main configuration files. Doing so gives you: better security, more perfomances and specifically easier maintenance as it is far more clear which directives applies to which content.

Comment: "much better to create `public_html/gl/` and `public_html/tlf/` and set the document roots to those respective directories." - Although if you are on shared hosting then that is probably not possible. However, you could leave `/public_html/` as the document root for the main domain (`gl.example`) and possibly configure the secondary "addon" domain to point to (ie. set the document root for) a directory outside of the main domain's public HTML space. eg. `/othersites/tlf/public_html/` - in order to keep the two domains entirely separate.

Answer (score 2):

> or the one under `/public_html/tlf/`

In the `/tlf/.htaccess` file add the following mod_rewrite directives at the top to redirect any requests to the `/tlf` subdirectory via the main domain to the subdomain's root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gl\.example [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://tlf.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```